# What is 'azureRmConnection.Id' in this Azure Pipelines build yaml template and how do I use it?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-build-task

## Problem Summary

I'm trying to build and deploy a project to an Azure Web App. I've already setup the Azure Web App. For the build pipeline I've taken the following build YAML template from Microsoft:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/templates/node.js-react-webapp-to-linux-on-azure.yml

I don't know what `{{ azureRmConnection.Id }}` in the `variables` section of the YAML template refers to or how to use it.

## Background

The double-brace (`{{ }}`) syntax is used to evaluate expressions, whereas pipeline variables are referenced with dollar (`$()`) syntax. So I think `azureRmConnection` is something the build should already have access to rather than requiring a pipeline variable to be set.

### What I've tried

- Searched Microsoft's docs, Google and StackOverflow.
- Looked on my Azure Web App to try to find anything obvious.
- Added the Web App's subscription Id as a variable reference to the pipeline with the name `azureRmConnection.Id`.
- Referenced Ansible YAML Syntax docs regarding the double-brace syntax: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

## The code

```
variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '{{ azureRmConnection.Id }}'
```

## Expected and actual results

### Expected

I expect the build to have a valid `azureRmConnection.Id` and therefore not fail due to it being missing or invalid.

### Actual

The build is failing with the following error:

> There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Deploy: Step input azureSubscription references service connection {{ azureRmConnection.Id }} which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."

Comment: Glad you have got a solution. You can accept it as answer. It will help other community users who have the same error.Thanks. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a new pipeline using the 'Node.js React Web App to Linux on Azure' wizard. I did think I'd tried that already but I must have used a different one previously. This had several more stages in it.

The wizard allowed me to choose my Azure Web App and Azure Subscription from dropdown menus.

The variables look like this in the YAML now:

```
variables:
  azureSubscription: '1234xx56-xx7x-[...]'
  webAppName: 'my-azure-web-app-name'
  environmentName: 'my-azure-web-app-name'
```

`azureSubscription` is my Azure Subscription ID.

`webAppName` is the name of my Azure Web App that I had previously setup on the Azure Portal.

The build has now run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security) and create an AzureRm service connection and use its name in place of that placeholder:

```
azureSubscription: 'my-azurerm-connection-name-goes-here'
```

Comment: (Left a couple comments and deleted because I've since resolved.)

Thanks for the info, I followed the docs you linked but still had a few issues not knowing what exactly to put for each value in the YAML. I'm going to post an answer with how I resolved it eventually.